# Splitting string containing boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript function

```
function cmd_parse( cmd )
{
   return cmd.split( /\s+/ );
}
```

If i do a function call like

```
words = cmd_parse("hello jay true");
```

it gives me

```
words[0]="hello"  words[1]="jay"  words[2]="true"
```

The third one was a bool value but after calling function it becomes a string value.Is there any way to preserve the bool state and still do the split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken that the third one was a bool... it's just the word "true" in a string. If you want an actual boolean value out of it, you're going to have to do a simple expression along the lines of

```
var b = (words[2] === 'true') ? true : false;
```